# Public dataset for monocular visual odometry

Tags: computer-vision, odometry

I am planning to develop a monocular visual odometry system. Is there any indoor dataset available to the public, along with the ground truth, on which I can test my approach?

Note: I am already aware of the KITTI Vision Benchmark Suite which provides stereo data for outdoor vehicles.

If anyone has access to the datasets used in the following paper [SVO14], it would be even more great: http://rpg.ifi.uzh.ch/docs/ICRA14_Forster.pdf

Comment: I think you can easily use only a single camera data from the KITTI dataset. For the ground truth you can use their quite precise GPS data.

Comment: I mentioned in my question that I needed an indoor dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a monocular dataset captured from a Micro Aerial Vehicle (MAV), and it has been been made available here:
http://projects.asl.ethz.ch/sfly/org/doku.php?id=mav%20datasets

In case the url stops worksing in the future, I am adding the name of the publication that came along with this dataset:
"A Benchmarking Tool for MAV Visual Pose Estimation"
Int. Conf. Control, Automation, Robotics and Vision
Singapore, 7-10th December 2010

Answer (score 3):

This is another more recent one, based on the paper [A Photometrically Calibrated Benchmark For Monocular Visual Odometry by Engel et al](http://vision.in.tum.de/_media/spezial/bib/engel2016monodataset.pdf):

http://vision.in.tum.de/data/datasets/mono-dataset

This gives both indoor and outdoor scenes, with calibration (or the corresponding sequences so you can calibrate yourself). I haven't tested it fully myself but it seems a rather complete dataset.

Answer (score 3):

http://vision.in.tum.de/data/datasets/rgbd-dataset

This is a set of recordings for the Kinect and Asus Xtion pro, which are all indoors (in offices and a hangar). It comes with precise ground truth from a motion capturing system.

The data is available as ROS bag files, but also as a tarball with png images with a text file for the trajectory.

There are also some scripts to benchmark your results against the ground truth.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there are monocular odometry datasets there, (I think it is mostly for standard 2D laser based SLAM), but you should check out [radish](http://radish.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Thanks a lot!
This might be useful for some future problem that I might tackle.